# recursive function to sum of first odd numbers python

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm trying to convert below code to recursive function but seems i'm quite confusing how could i write below in recursive function. could help me to give some thoughts?

Basically, what I'm generating below is the sum of the first n odd numbers.

```
def sum_odd_n(n):
    total=0
    j=2*n-1
    i=1
    if i>j:
        return 1
    else: 
        total =((j+1)/2)**2
    i+=2
    return total


> >>> sum_odd_n(5)
> 25.0
> >>> sum_odd_n(4)
> 16.0
> >>> sum_odd_n(1)
> 1.0
```

Comment: Your function has constant time complexity (`O(1)`). Recursive functions are generally used to replace the corresponding iterative functions. So, I don't see any need for converting your code to a recursive function, which will have linear time complexity (`O(n)`).

Comment: If you want to learn recursion, first try to write the function iteratively (i.e. without using direct formulae). Then convert it to a recursive function.

Comment: that is what i confusing. What does direct formula and recursive mean? what i though was my above code is  recursive..in such a way that " if i>j: return " is termination condition and the "else statement" is recursive call.

Answer (score 1):

This smells somewhat like homework so I'm going to offer some advice instead of a solution.

Recursion is about expressing a problem in terms of itself.

Suppose you know the sum of the odd numbers from N to N - 2.
Can you write the total sum in terms of this sum and the function itself (or a related helper function)?

Comment: total =((j+1)/2)**2.. the math background i use is 1 => 1 = 1

3 => 1+3 = 2power2=4

5 => 1+3+5 = 3power2=9

7 => 1+3+5+7 = 4power2=16

Comment: yes..by j=2*n-1, i will know the last odd number to add. At first, i thought the above code i created is recursive function but unfortunately it is not.

Comment: Too much math. Try expressing the total sum in another way: totalSum = currentSum + sumOfRemainingNumbersToCheck.

Answer (score 1):

Recursive functions have at least one base case and at least one recursive call. Here are some hints:

```
def f(n):
  # Base case - for which
  # n do we already know the answer
  # and can return it without
  # more function calls? (Clearly,
  # this must also terminate any
  # recursive sequence.)

  if n == ???:
    return ???

  # Otherwise, lets say we know the answer
  # to f(n - 1) and assign it to
  # the variable, 'rest'

  rest = f(n - 1)

  # What do we need to do with 'rest'
  # to return the complete result

  return rest + ???
```

Fill out the question marks and you'll have the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
def sum_of_odd(n):
if n>0:
    x=(n*2)-1
    return x+sum_of_odd(n-1)
else:
    return 0
```

The answer of this:

```
sum_of_odd(5)
```

will be:

```
25
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
def sum_odd_n(n):
    if n>0:
        if n==1:
            return 1
        else:
            return 2*n-1 + sum_odd_n(n-1)
```

Comment: Please read [Answering homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/8881141).

Comment: @MatthiasFripp It works fine . Can you explain why it needs to be changed ?

Comment: Sorry, I was being hasty and thinking about summing the first n integers, in which case the change would have been to `n`. I was also being cagey to try to point the asker in the right direction without giving away the answer (since it looks like a homework question). But that didn't help much, since I was wrong!